# How can I use a library dependency in the definition of an sbt task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am defining an sbt task that needs to call code in a library. Here is a build.sbt file with what I've tried so far:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.some.company" %% "some-lib" % "1.0.0")

val doSomething = taskKey[Unit]("does something")

doSomething := {
  import com.some.company.function
  function()
}
```

The imports do not work.  How do I define a task that depends on code in an external library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To build the `.sbt` file itself in the root directory, SBT uses information in the `project` directory. So put a `build.sbt` in the `project` directory and set the `libraryDependencies` key there:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.some.company" %% "some-lib" % "1.0.0")
```

So, to clarify, you now have two `build.sbt` files:

1. `./build.sbt`
2. `./project/build.sbt`

Comment: Found the official docs for this:http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Organizing-Build.html

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942473/sbt-task-to-load-system-environment-variables