# Sbt task to load system environment variables

Tags: scala, yaml, sbt

I have some yaml file with system environment variables needed for service run.

```yaml
system:
  service: "name"
  port: 123
```

I must have all these variables, loaded to the shell before run service start. But I want to load them by some sbt variable, maybe `load-dev-env`.

The main problem that I can't import libraries for yaml parsing (`circe-yaml`) into sbt shell execution and all imports like

```
import io.circe._
import cats._
```

are failed due to `circe is no the subpackage of io or etc...`

1. I've tried to put libraryDependencies to the `./project/build.sbt` - no success

The last one thing - read all key/values manually but it doesn't look correct

Has someone done smth like this?

Comment: I would let the service read the file, not the SBT. It sounds backwards to do it via SBT. Additionally I wouldn't run service from SBT unless you are just testing/developing. Just compile a JAR file and run your service which reads from this file.

Comment: It's not the main need)
The service is wrapped into docker, the container has environment variables, read from that config file. 
So, for local service run without wrapping new codebase into new docker image (it takes some time and don't like spending it) I must load env variables into the shell manually or via some sbt task, it could be also bash script to read it)) but I prefer sbt task

Comment: Looks like you can do this (I haven't tried): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828688/how-can-i-use-a-library-dependency-in-the-definition-of-an-sbt-task/34829574

Comment: Thanks. 
Have seen it before and tried.. but without success(

Answer (score 1):

This `SBT` build definition works:

Dir structure:

```
build.sbt
src/main/resources/config.yml
project/build.sbt
project/build.properties
```

**build.sbt:**

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"

lazy val hello = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Hello",
    //libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-yaml" % "0.14.1"
  )

lazy val loadEnv = TaskKey[Unit]("load-dev-env")
loadEnv := {
  import _root_.io.circe._
  import _root_.io.circe.yaml.parser
  import scala.io.Source
  val filename = "src/main/resources/config.yml"
  val confStr = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString("\n")
  println(confStr)
  val json: Either[ParsingFailure, Json] = parser.parse(confStr)
  println(json)
}
```

**project/build.sbt:**

```
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-yaml" % "0.14.1"
```

**project/build.properties:**

```
sbt.version=1.6.1
```

**src/main/resources/config.yml:**

```
--- 
system: 
  port: 123
  service: name
```

Example of running it:

```
sbt:Hello> loadDevEnv
--- 
system: 
  port: 123
  service: name

Right({
  "system" : {
    "port" : 123,
    "service" : "name"
  }
})
```

It prints string from file followed by parsed json.

The important details are:

- You need to put library dependency in the other build file in `project` dir.
- You need to use `_root_` because otherwise imports don't resolve if they are not part of core Scala or SBT plugins. At least I didn't find the way yet.

You can checkout the code here: https://github.com/izmailoff/sbt-import-test.

**--- UPDATE ---:**

I've added the full example in the repo. That required some changes since you can't update SBT settings from a `Task` you need to do it in a `Command`. Updated files below:

**build.sbt:**

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"

// This is needed to get new env values from SBT:
fork := true

lazy val hello = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Hello",
    //libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-yaml" % "0.14.1"
  )

commands += Command.command("loadDevEnv") { state =>
  val env = Config.getEnvFromConf()
  val envStr = Config.prettyPrint(env)
  s"set envVars ++= ${envStr}" :: state
}
```

**project/Build.scala:**

```
case class Service(port: Integer, service: String)

case class System(system: Service)

object Config {

    def getEnvFromConf(): Map[String, String] = {
        val filename = "src/main/resources/config.yml"
        val confStr = readConfig(filename)
        val conf = parseConfig(confStr)
        println(conf)
        val env = toEnv(conf)
        env
    }

    def readConfig(filename: String): String = {
      import scala.io.Source
      Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString("\n") // use better way?
    }

    def parseConfig(conf: String): System = {
      import _root_.io.circe._
      import _root_.io.circe.yaml
      import _root_.io.circe.yaml._
      import _root_.io.circe.yaml.syntax._
      import _root_.io.circe.generic.auto._
      import cats.syntax.either._
      val json: Either[ParsingFailure, Json] = yaml.parser.parse(conf)
      json
        .leftMap(err => err: Error)
        .flatMap(_.as[System])
        .valueOr(throw _)
    }

    def toEnv(conf: System): Map[String, String] = {
      Map(s"service.${conf.system.service}" -> conf.system.port.toString)
    }

    def prettyPrint(x: Map[String, String]): String = {
      "Map(" + (x.map{ case (k, v) => s""""${k}"->"${v}""""}).mkString(", ") + ")"
    }

}
```

**project.build.sbt:**

```
val circeVersion = "0.14.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-yaml",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"
).map(_ % circeVersion)
```

**src/main/scala/Main.scala:**

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Found the following environment variable:")
  println(System.getenv("service.name"))
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

Run SBT from your OS shell:

```
> sbt
```

Run the app to check if environment variables are set:

```
sbt:Hello> run
[info] running (fork) Main 
[info] Found the following environment variable:
[info] null
```

Getting `null`. Load env:

```
sbt:Hello> loadDevEnv
[info] Defining envVars
[info] The new value will be used by Compile / bspBuildTargetRun, Compile / bspScalaMainClassesItem and 6 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to Hello (in build file:/home/tvc/repos/sbt_test/)
```

Run the app to check again:

```
sbt:Hello> run
[info] running (fork) Main 
[info] Found the following environment variable:
[info] 123
```

Found value `123`.

Comment: That's looking great!!
Yeah, maybe the `_root_` makes the magic.
I'll check it - thanks a lot.